# Localization and language difference issue in android

Tags: java, android, layout, bluetooth, localization

I'll try to make this short, So I created this Bluetooth Connection app and everything works perfect in my phone but i noticed an awful problem when I tested it on my friend's phone.

the problem is I'm using Linearlayout and two different buttons with image background on it for each row which stands aside each other, the circle standing on the left side of the rectangle which is correct and that's how it works on my phone, but when it comes to my friend's phone which has a different Language ( Language and Input in android settings ) the circle is on the right side of the rectangle.

Please note that i already know the fact that this can be fixed if he change the phone language to English just like mine, But i'm looking for a solution which wouldn't cause any trouble for all type of costumers in my country with two different phone languages.

Well, How am i supposed to fix this ?

[How it looks on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APOg6.png)

[How it looks on my friend's phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJCrn.jpg)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">



<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200dp">


<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/circle1"
    android:background="@drawable/redcircle  />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/greenCircle"
    android:background="@drawable/greencircle"
    android:alpha="0"/>




 </FrameLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/rect1"
        android:text="Bluetooth Turn On / Off"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:background="@drawable/rects"
        android:layout_weight="1" />



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/circle2"
        android:background="@drawable/gomb"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/rect2"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="View paired Devices"
        android:textColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:background="@drawable/rects"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/circle3"
        android:background="@drawable/gomb"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/rect3"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Scan for new Devices"
        android:background="@drawable/rects"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your friend's phone is in a right-to-left language, and your app "supports" right-to-left. While supporting RTL is an admirable goal, sometimes it's not feasible.

You have a few different options here. The fastest/easiest for you is to disable RTL support from your app. Add this attr to the `<application>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Or, you could try to actually provide the necessary support for RTL within your app. In this case, that probably means specifying an alternative drawable for your button background. If you currently have these:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/background.png
res/drawable-xhdpi/background.png
res/drawable-xxhdpi/background.png
```

You'd need to add these:

```
res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi/background.png
res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi/background.png
res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi/background.png
```

And you'd put the curvature on the right side of the button instead of the left.